# Is it possible to override the generic type in a factory method for abstract classes?

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I have a factory class that returns concrete instances inheriting from an abstract type. These concrete instances also have a generic property for their data type, as each instance requires a different data type. The Data property also exists on the abstract type since it is set in the factory.

```
public static class FactoryClass 
{
  public static TType CreateNewClass<TType>(object data) 
        where TType : AbstractClass<object>, new()
  {
    var newClass = new TType {Data = data};
    // do some stuff
    // keep track of all created types in a list
    List.Add(newClass);
    return newClass;
  }

  private List<AbstractClass<object>> MyList = new List<AbstractClass<object>>()
}

public abstract class AbstractClass<TData>
{
  internal AbstractClass()
  {
    // do constructor things
  }

  protected SomeCommonFunction()
  {
    // common code for abstract base class
  }

  public abstract void DoSomethingToData();

  TData Data;
}

public class ExampleClass : AbstractClass<string[]>
{
  public override void DoSomethingToData()
  {
    // sort the strings or something
    // call the abstract code
  }
}
```

When I try and call `FactoryClass.CreateNewClass<ExampleClass>(myStringArray)` I get an error that it needs to be castable to `AbstractClass<object>`

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You refer to AbstractClass, AbstractBase, and AbstractBaseClass. Just lots of typos?

Comment: Yeah, whoops. I retyped it from scratch as it was easier than scrubbing the code I was working on in to something legible for a SO question. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is the problem:

```
where TType : AbstractClass<object>
```

That constraint is exactly the one the compiler is complaining about.

It sounds to me like you really want something like this:

```
public static TContainer CreateNewClass<TContainer, TData>(TData data) 
    where TContainer : AbstractClass<TData>, new()
```

Unfortunately that then requires you to specify *both* type arguments to the method - but at least it's safe in terms of the type of data you're using. You may be able to work around this by creating two generic methods and a separate class to be used between them, allowing you to write something like:

```
FactoryClass.For(myStringArray).CreateNewClass<ExampleClass>();
```

The `For` method would return a generic type with a type argument of `string[]`, and then `CreateNewClass` would be an instance method which took the container type for the data type.

However, your list simply can't work in its current form. You may want to create a *non-generic* base class for `AbstractClass`:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    // Anything which doesn't use TData
}
```

then:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<TData> : AbstractClass
```

At that point the list in your factory would be a `List<AbstractClass>`; you wouldn't know the data type of each entry in a compile-time-safe way... which makes complete sense as each element could use a different type.

(Oh, and of course your list field will need to be static if you want to access it from a static method...)